# ReadFuture object not able to read message

Tags: java

I am using a web application A which send a request to another application B using IoSession as below. B is a standalone java application server which 
listens on a specified port and using NioSocketAcceptor class to creatsocket.

Below is the client side code:

```
session.write(dom);
try {
                // Read the message received here
                ReadFuture future = session.read();
                // Wait until a message is received.
                future.await(15000);

                message = future.getMessage();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("Could not receive the response from Core: ", e);
            } finally {
                // Release the session used
                try {
                    //releasing connection here
                } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                    logger.error("Could not release the Connection used: ", e);
                }
            }
```

At server side, I am using below code to write the response back to client.

```
// doc is an object for org.w3c.dom.Document class and session is an object of IoSession class.
session.write(doc);
```

The code works fine except few cases. As observed, mostly under load conditions, the client is not able to read the message from the session while as per server side logs, the response was already generated and there is no exception/error while writing the doc object to the session.

I am not able to get the root cause of the problem here. Had been researching over the same but none of the problem statement matched this one. I have also tried taking thread dump which didn't show any kind of deadlock. Please help.

Comment: What happens when `await(15000)` doesn't receive a message after 15 seconds?

Comment: Are you using a framework such as Apache MINA? Because `IoSession` and `ReadFuture` are not standard Java classes.